# Get value of input type=date as a string

Tags: javascript

I want to extract the value from date field, but it doesn't work. I add the input this way:

```
var question0  = "<div id='0'><p>Please, enter the date: </p><br>" 
                       + "<input type=\"date\" id=\'contractdate\'></input><br></div>";
```

Here is how I tried to receive the value:

```
var text_Contract_Date     = document.getElementById('contractdate').value;
//tried the code below, but didn't work
// var text_Contract_Date  = document.getElementById('contractdate').valueAsDate;
// var text_Contract_Date  = new Date(document.getElementById('contractdate').valueAsDate);
```

So, I want to get the value from input as a string, using pure JavaScript, because then it will be used to fill in the document.

Comment: `.value` gets the value as a string. When you say "bu didn't work", what do you mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: The result from `.value` is already a string.  Do you mean you want it as a `Date` object?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/ledeqecisu/edit?html,js,console,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, there was a problem with variable, @deaponn helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information to resolve the issue, so I can only guess that you are probably inserting your variable into the DOM the wrong way.
If I call `document.body.append(question0)`, only text is shown and not the tags.
Try moving content of `question0` variable to your html file, then add onchange handler to your input, and also modify your .js file like below

```js
function handleChange(event){
  // here you can do whatever you want with the value of the input
  alert(event.target.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id='contractdate' onchange="handleChange(event)"></input>
```

If you desperately want to create your HTML inside of Javascript, you have to do this like this:

```
// create div and assign id to it
const myDiv = document.createElement("div")
myDiv.id = '0'

// create p and set its contents
const myP = document.createElement("p")
p.textContent = "Please, enter the date: "

// create input, assign id to it and set its type to date
const myInput = document.createElement("input")
myInput.id = 'contractdate'
myInput.type = "date"

// put everything in your document
myDiv.appendChild(myP)
myDiv.appendChild(myInput)
document.body.appendChild(myDiv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var dateEntered = new Date(text_Contract_Date);
```

Comment: That returns a Date object, not a string.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Comment: Thank you, I also tried it and than formatted date as a string :) but basically I changed my code as the answer above